# Unicode decode error while iterating through all txt files in folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to write the expression `|    SYS` into each single txt file in the folder. However I am getting the Unicode decode error. I have suspicion that it might be because of missing `r` in the string `with open(txt_file, "r") as f:`

My code is:

```
import os
import csv
import glob

cwd = os.getcwd()

directory = cwd

output = cwd

txt_files = os.path.join(directory, '*.txt')

for txt_file in glob.glob(txt_files):
    with open(txt_file, "r") as f:
        a = f.read()
        print(a)
#Now writing into the file with the prepend line + old file data
    with open(txt_file, "w") as f:
        f.write("|   SYS" + a)
        #below code to verify the data in the file
        with open(txt_file, "r") as f:
            b = f.read()
            print(b)
```

And the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxxxxx/Downloads/TEST2/Searchcombine.py", line 15, in <module>
    a = f.read()
  File "C:\Python\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 1060662: character maps to <undefined>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not safest with most files, I solved it by adding `ignore error` in the line `(txt_file, "r") as f:`, making it `(txt_file, errors='ignore') as f:`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to set the encoding argument when calling open():

```
with open(txt_file, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
```

Comment: Still the same: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxxxxxx/Downloads/TEST2/Searchcombine.py", line 15, in <module>
    a = f.read()
  File "C:\Python\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 192: invalid start byte`

Comment: @user9799161 Use the [chardet](https://pypi.org/project/chardet/) module to find your file encoding if it's not utf-8, and use the proper encoding when opening the file.

Comment: any other ideas?

Comment: Open the file in binary (mode rb/wb), you clearly don't care about their content not making any sense so adding more garbage to the existing garbage isn't a huge change.